# Iterate through dropdowns and then copy/paste a range for each iteration into a new tab

Tags: excel, vba

Here is an example Google Sheets to demonstrate the problem. In practice I am using Excel and a more complex model but this follows the same structure: [Google Sheets link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ddIWA8IBDLZXp9FA2OU7AmIbisVtX4xugeclPDPB-zA/edit?usp=sharing)

I have a worksheet (*Output*) with five Data Validation lists (contained in range C2:C7). I want to iterate through all 216 combinations, which produce different outputs contained in range C9:C12 (i.e., there is a calculation that take places dependents on the Data Validation values). I then want to copy the results for each combination into a new worksheet (the highlighted cells in *Summary*).

I've tried the option of recording a macro by manually changing each Data Validation List, linking the outputs and then and value pasting the row, but this take a long time to do 216 times and I assume is very inefficient (I'm new to VBA!). For example to fill in the first two rows of the *Summary* tab:

```
' Select dropdown boxes
Sheets("Output").Select
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "A"
Range("C3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "D"
Range("C4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "F"
Range("C5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "H"
Range("C6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "J"
Range("C7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "M"

' Copy first row
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Output!R[7]C[-4]"
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Output!R[8]C[-5]"
Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Output!R[9]C[-6]"
Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Output!R[10]C[-7]"
Range("G2:J2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("G2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

' Change dropdown selection to match second row
Sheets("Output").Select
Range("C5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "I"

' Copy second row
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range("G3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Output!R[6]C[-4]"
Range("H3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Output!R[7]C[-5]"
Range("I3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Output!R[8]C[-6]"
Range("J3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Output!R[9]C[-7]"
Range("G3:J3").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("G3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: It may help to include the code you recorded and show what you have tried instead of just saying that you tried something.

Comment: Hey, with 216 iterations, when you change the value on the dropdown, a calculation is tied to it? And you need to output all these results? Is that correct? And by validation list you refer to `Data Validation`? I'm sorry, I cannot view your google sheet, unfortunately.

Comment: @L42 Yes that's correct, the calculation is in Range C9:C12 and is dependent upon the dropdown values selected and I want to output the results for each combination, and yes I refer to Data Validation

Comment: You might find this useful - https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-range-cells/

Comment: Is your validation list from a range or a string separated by delimiter?

Comment: @L42 from a string separated by delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, please try this.

```
Sub stantial()
  Dim dVal1, dVal2, dVal3, dVal4
  Dim c As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, tR As Integer
  
  Const delim As String = ";" 'update delimiter based on your setting
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With Sheets("Output")
    'get your validation list into array
    dVal1 = Split(.Range("C2").Validation.Formula1, delim)
    dVal2 = Split(.Range("C3").Validation.Formula1, delim)
    dVal3 = Split(.Range("C4").Validation.Formula1, delim)
    dVal4 = Split(.Range("C5").Validation.Formula1, delim)
    tR = 2
    'iterate to change the values
    For i = LBound(dVal1) To UBound(dVal1): For j = LBound(dVal2) To UBound(dVal2)
    For k = LBound(dVal3) To UBound(dVal3): For l = LBound(dVal4) To UBound(dVal4)
      'set validation list values
      .Range("C2").Value2 = dVal1(i)
      .Range("C3").Value2 = dVal2(j)
      .Range("C4").Value2 = dVal3(k)
      .Range("C5").Value2 = dVal4(l)
      'copy the result
      .Range("C9:C12").Copy
      'paste to destination sheet
      Sheets("Summary").Range("G" & tR).PasteSpecial _
        xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, , , True
      tR = tR + 1
    Next: Next: Next: Next
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I put comments in the code to let you know what is happening. HTH.
**Important**: This assumes `C2:C5` have existing string delimited data validation, otherwise it will result to an error.